# logstash_forwarder connected to lostash-server-IP but never receive event

Tags: json, logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I installed elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, ngix and logstash-forwarder at same server to centralized logs. The log file (allapp.json) is a json file with logs entry like this:

```
"{\"timestamp\":\"2015-08-30 19:42:26.724\",\"MAC_Address\":\"A8:7C:01:CB:2D:09\",\"DeviceID\":\"96f389972de989d1\",\"RunningApp\":\"null{com.tools.app_logs\\/com.tools.app_logs.Main}{com.gtp.nextlauncher\\/com.gtp.nextlauncher.LauncherActivity}{com.android.settings\\/com.android.settings.Settings$WifiSettingsActivity}{com.android.incallui\\/com.android.incallui.InCallActivity}{com.tools.app_logs\\/com.tools.app_logs.Main}{com.gtp.nextlauncher\\/com.gtp.nextlauncher.LauncherActivity}{com.android.settings\\/com.android.settings.Settings$WifiSettingsActivity}{com.android.incallui\\/com.android.incallui.InCallActivity}\",\"PhoneName\":\"samsung\",\"IP\":\"192.168.1.101\"}"
```

my logstash.conf is:

```
 input {
lumberjack {
port => 5002
type => "logs"
ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
}   
udp {
type   => "json"
port   => 5001 
}
  } 
 filter {
  json {
  "source" => "message"
  }
}
output {
elasticsearch { host => localhost }
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

my logstash-forwarder.conf (at same system that logstash is installed) is:

```
{
"network":{ 
"servers": [ "192.168.1.102:5002" ],
"timeout": 15,
"ssl ca": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt" },
  "files": [
       {
           "paths":[ "/var/log/app-log/allapp.json" ],
           "fields": { "type": "json" }
       }
       ]
}
```

my elasticsearch.yml is:

```
network.host: localhost
```

when i enter `tail -f /var/log/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder.err` in terminal i get this:

```
2015/09/04 11:33:05.282495 Waiting for 1 prospectors to initialise
2015/09/04 11:33:05.282544 Launching harvester on new file: /var/log/app-log/allapp.json
2015/09/04 11:33:05.282591 harvest: "/var/log/app-log/allapp.json" (offset snapshot:0)
2015/09/04 11:33:05.283709 All prospectors initialised with 0 states to persist
2015/09/04 11:33:05.283806 Setting trusted CA from file: /etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt
2015/09/04 11:33:05.284254 Connecting to [192.168.1.102]:5002 (192.168.1.102) 
2015/09/04 11:33:05.417174 Connected to 192.168.1.102
```

the allapp.json file has been update frequently and new log add in it but in above I never see the log which looks like :

**Registrar received 1 events**

**Registrar received 23 events ...**

**In addition i have another client with logstash-forwarder to send its logs to kibana, logstash-forwarder on that client works correctly and logs from that shown in kibana but at this one client doesn't.**
All result in kibana are look like this:

```
    Time                            file    
September 4th 2015, 06:14:00.942    /var/log/suricata/eve.json
September 4th 2015, 06:14:00.942    /var/log/suricata/eve.json
September 4th 2015, 06:14:00.942    /var/log/suricata/eve.json
September 4th 2015, 06:14:00.942    /var/log/suricata/eve.json
```

I want to see logs from **/var/log/app-log/allapp.json** too in kibana, what is problem? why they aren't shown in kibana? why one client work correctly but logstash-forwarder on same system with logstash doesn't work?

Comment: Can you check your logstash.log file on the machine which is getting allapp.json logs ? Maybe the elasticsearch and logstash are not able to make a connection.

Comment: in logstash.log: ' {:timestamp=>"2015-09-07T11:19:58.811000+0430", :message=>"SIGTERM received. Shutting down the pipeline.", :level=>:warn}' 
in logstash.err:   ` Sep 07, 2015 11:20:36 AM org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode start
    INFO: [logstash-ubuntu-3991-11624] started`        
So what should i do now???

Comment: No body has any idea???

Comment: For me what worked was updating the elasticsearch plugin in logstash, changing my config like the following link: https://deviantony.wordpress.com/2014/09/23/how-to-setup-an-elasticsearch-cluster-with-logstash-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: its seem good idea, please explain more! the link is not work, its damage.

Comment: changing config not working for me,